$\lg^* n = O( \lg \lg n)$ proof?
Let $\lg^* n$ be the iterated logarithm (base 2). Then show that $\lg^* n = O( \lg \lg n)$ i.e. there exists some $C, n_0$ s.t. $\forall n \ge n_0 \Rightarrow \lg^* n \le C \lg \lg n$.
I looked this up online, and pretty much every answer says "Wikipedia says that $\lg^* n$ is the second slowest growing function known except the inverse Ackermann function, and hence that statement must be true". But how do you formally show this?

Do you already read this ?

@Kermatoni That's not a formal argument

If you already believe that $\mathop{\rm lg}^* n \le n$, then the desired assertion follows from $\mathop{\rm lg}^* n = 2 + \mathop{\rm lg}^*(\log\log n)$ (when $n$ is large enough).

Nice, but any way to show $\lg^* n \le n$ (or by a further application of your method $\lg^* n \le 2^n$?

There is no slowest growing function.

As computer scientists, let's keep all our logs as base 2.
Now recall the definition:
$$\log^* n := \begin{cases}
0 & n \le 1 \\
1 + \log^* \log n & n > 1.
\end{cases}$$
First claim that for all $n$ we have $\log^* n \le n$.
You can prove this claim by induction, but I'll omit the details.
Now take any $n > 4$. This is large enough that we know the recursive branch will be taken at least twice:
$$\log^*n = 1 + \log^* \log n = 2 + \log^* \log \log n$$
Using the claim we have
$$\log^* n \le 2 + \log \log n.$$
From here you can choose your $C$ and conclude.

Just to completely formalize this argument, here is the induction argument showing $\lg^* n \le n$.  Use strong induction i.e. assume $\lg^* i \le i$ forall $i \le m$ for some $m$. Then $\lg^* (m+1) = 1 + \lg^* \lg (m+1) \le 1 + \lg (m + 1)$ as $\lg (m + 1) < m + 1$ and the induction hypothesis. And then for any natural number $m$, you can check that $1 + \lg (m + 1) < m + 1$ showing that $\lg^* (m+1) < m + 1$ which shows the induction case.
